# How to share an array of image file links or multiple images through socialsharing plugin in ionic?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4

I am trying to share an array of dynamically created image file links through social sharing plugin in ionicv4. Right now I am testing it with WhatsApp. But it gives me a TS error that can not pass arr[] in type string. I do understand this error but need a solution to this. i have done something like

```
this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp(null, imageArr , null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the 2nd parameter should be a string, and your imageArr variable is an array. Try to pass a string instead

Can you try to create a function like

```
const ArrayLikeImages = ('yourImage1', 'yourImage2', 'yourImage3') => arguments;
```

and then the line

```
this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp(null, ArrayLikeImages , null);
```

Comment: Yes, it accepts string but I have multiple image file links which I want to pass in one time.

Comment: shareViaWhatsApp: (message?: string, fileOrFileArray?: string | ArrayLike<string>, url?: string, successCallback?: SocialSharingSuccessCallback<never>, errorCallback?: SocialSharingErrorCallback) => void

Comment: ok, images must be a string or an ArrayLike<string>. Maybe you can try my edit post

Comment: The plugin takes the entire string as one URL and Whatsapp ends up with an error - does not support this format.

Answer (score 0):

use the forloop in async

```
const imageurls = [arrayofImageLinks];
let array = [];


for (var _i = 0; _i < imageurls.length; _i++) {
    const url = imageurls[_i];

this.http.get(url, {
            responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob
          })
          .toPromise()
          .then(async (res: any) => {
            const imgBlob = new Blob([res._body], {
              type: res.headers.get("Content-Type")
            });

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(imgBlob);
            reader.onloadend = async () => {
              const base64data = reader.result;
              array.push(base64data);
            };
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
          });

}

this.socialSharing.shareViaWhatsApp("Title", "", array).then(() => {
//do something when done
}).catch(err => {
// Error Occured
console.log(err); 
});
```

Comment: I want to share in a unique platform at once. But here the this.socialSharing.share will give the user all platform options. Moreover, I can pass the image file link array directly into this.socialSharing.share, what is the need of doing the above for loop?

Comment: you are sharing the links but that method gives you the actual images as they are all converted into base64 so they will be no need of clicking individual image links to have access to the image ...